# TinyMCE make some class of div not-editable

Tags: jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

Is it possible with tinyMCE plugin that if there is some div having class `.not-editable` - it will be displayed inside tinymce, all this content will be divible normally, but user will not be able to edit anything inside it, the only thing user will be able to do is to remove/move it?

So for example it would work with this content:

```
<div class="editable">This text can be editet</div>

<div class="not-editable"><span>Whatever</span> here cannot be edited</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. I've figured it out.

You need to enable [this](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Plugin%3anoneditable) plugin, and then anything with class `mceNonEditable` will be treated as sinlge character.